# please wait loading message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**Screenshot of the page**

[image]

**ASPX CODE**

```
<div style="width:729px;background:white;">
<div id="tabs">
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDefinitions" runat="server">Definitions</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEmployees" runat="server">Employees</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonFamily" runat="server">Family</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonHomeTown" runat="server">Home Town</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonOtherThanHomeTown" runat="server">Other Than Home Town</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAdmissibility" runat="server">Admissibility</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonTypesOfLTC" runat="server">Types Of LTC</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonBlockPeriod" runat="server">Block Period</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEntitlement" runat="server">Entitlement</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAdvance" runat="server">Advance</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAdjustmentofadvance" runat="server">Adjustment of advance</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonReimbursement" runat="server">Reimbursement</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonCarryOverForfeitureofclaim" runat="server">Carry Over & Forfeiture of claim</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1RelaxationsInterpretations" runat="server">Relaxations & Interpretations</asp:LinkButton></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
Public Sub loadContent(ByVal PageName As String)
  Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LeaveDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
  Dim _da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PageHeader,PageContent FROM PageKeeper WHERE PageName='" & PageName & "'", _con)
  Dim _table As New DataTable

  Try
    _con.Open()
    _da.Fill(_table)
    _con.Close()
    _con.Dispose()
    With _table.Rows(0)
      h4header.InnerText = .Item(0)
      divUpdatePanel.InnerHtml = .Item(1)
      Me.Title = .Item(0)
    End With
  Catch ex As Exception
   'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    divUpdatePanel.InnerText = "No Data Found"
  Finally
    _con.Close()
    _con.Dispose()
  End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButtonEmployees_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonEmployees.Click
  loadContent("Employees")
End Sub
```

**PROBLEM**

When i click on the tabs ,it takes a few secs to reflect the data...i want to show a **"please wait loading"** message to the user which should disappear automatically after the data is shown.

**UPDATE:** ASPX code is inside an `UPdatePanel` so clicking on the tabs does an Asynchronous postback.Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the AJAX controls now available for ASP.net. You basically want to intercept the call before it is sent to the server, display your message and when the request is returned, remove the message. jQuery can work wonders with it's .ajax() method.

Comment: @MunkiPhD Kindly point me to a good article...if you know any.Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because you posted an image and a boatload of code before you posted your two-sentence "How do I show a 'please wait' message while a page loads?" question?

Comment: [jQuery .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and your [Google search!](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+asp.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Ajax you can update the partially. or you can try to use Async Triggers in the update panel. [Ajax Update Panels](http://weblogs.asp.net/stoianbucovich/archive/2008/01/30/asp-net-2-0-ajax-update-panel-and-update-progress.aspx)

alternativily, you can use [Update Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx), to show the indication. like this .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

asscoiate your update panel to the update progreess area.

```
<asp:updateprogress id="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" associatedupdatepanelid="UpdatePanel1" dynamiclayout="true">
<progresstemplate>
<img src="support/images/loading.gif">
</progresstemplate>
</asp:updateprogress>
```

Comment: if i use `UpdateProgress`...it seems i cannot position it..i want it at the center of the page...but now it shows up at the bottom.

Comment: css cant be applied i guess...because if i put the image inside a div ...the progress bar stops showing

Answer (score 1):

Best to use AJAX for this kind of thing. Threading is not going to help because the server will wait until all those threads have finished before returning the response to the client. Load the page with the message and then load the data using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. place the "divUpdatePanel" inside and [asp:UpdatePanel](http://weblogs.asp.net/stoianbucovich/archive/2008/01/30/asp-net-2-0-ajax-update-panel-and-update-progress.aspx). Set linkbutton as [Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) to achieve this